# Numbers disappears with \rowcolor in siunitx table with tableformat=x.0

Tags: tables, siunitx, rowcolor

Following the siunitx documentation in regards to '7.13 Creating a column with numbers and units' and '7.14 Tables with heading rows' I have tried to make a table a table with currency as unit. The problem arises when I use `\rowcolor`. [image: Problem table]

I can patch up the problem by setting `table-format=7.1` but this creates unwanted space or deleting `\rowcolor[gray]{0.92}`, but I want the alternating rowcolors.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}
{lSS[table-format=7.0]@{\,}s[table-unit-alignment = left]} \toprule
Company name                    &{Employees}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Turnover} \\\midrule \rowcolor[gray]{0.92}
JOHNSON CONTROLS APS            &616       &1293896    & \si{USD} \\
SKOV A/S GLYNGOERE              &304       &682921     & \si{USD} \\\rowcolor[gray]{0.92}
EXHAUSTO A/S                    &262       &410914     & \si{USD} \\
SONDEX A/S                      &116       &616943     & \si{USD} \\\rowcolor[gray]{0.92}
NILAN A/S                       &114       &137        & \si{USD} \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
I found a crude solution by setting `table-format=7.1` and adding `\hspace{-0.7em}` before every unit/currency.
[image: Crude solution]

Comment: Why don't you add the repeaded unit to the column header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the gap a bit wider to prevent overlapping of the columns:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
        l
        S[table-format=3.0]
        S[table-format=7.0]
        @{\hskip 0.08in}
        s[table-unit-alignment = left]
    }
\toprule
Company name                    &{Employees}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Turnover} \\\midrule \rowcolor[gray]{0.92}
JOHNSON CONTROLS APS            &616       &1293896    & \si{USD} \\
SKOV A/S GLYNGOERE              &304       &682921     & \si{USD} \\\rowcolor[gray]{0.92}
EXHAUSTO A/S                    &262       &410914     & \si{USD} \\
SONDEX A/S                      &116       &616943     & \si{USD} \\\rowcolor[gray]{0.92}
NILAN A/S                       &114       &137        & \si{USD} \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]